# ubuntu 16.04 kernel recompile

Tags: kernel, compiling

I have downloaded Ubuntu kernel using:

```
git clone https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/xenial
```

I do following to compile the kernel:

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs  --> select amd64.generic
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

I change the kernel drivers file. I.e. `drivers/pci/pcie/aspm.c` with erroneous code and try to retrigger compilation using `fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic`. And I see package is build even if `drivers/pci/pcie/aspm.c` contained a garbaged code. That means recompilation does not work with above command directly.

Could you please help me to know how to recompile and rebuild the package quickly after making kernel source changes?

Comment: It does work. Probably `aspm.c` is not used according to `.config`.